# Qt add item in the center of the scene/ view

Tags: qt, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsscene

Greetings,

I'm trying to add a QGraphicsItem exactly in the center of the current screen.
My QGraphicsScene is very large (10k X 10K), so the QGraphicsView cannot show it entirely, there are scroll bars.

I can't find any function to return me the rectangle of my current screen, i searched in all QGraphicsScene and QGraphicsView functions.
There are functions to return the scene rect (it returns a rect 10k X 10k but it's useless) and there are functions to return the mouse position, but i need to move my mouse and click on a menu so the mouse will no longer be inside the scene and the item will be generated outside the visible space...

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should map your top left corner (0,0) of your viewport to the scene. Width & height are equal to the viewport's rect width & height.

To get the rectangle of the current screen try this,:

```
QRect exposedRect(graphicsView.mapToScene(0,0).toPoint(), graphicsView.viewport()->rect().size());
```

I assume you can handle it from here.

Comment: Greetings and thank you for answer.
Unfortunately it doesn't work.

I tried graphicsView.viewport().pos() and graphicsView.viewport()->rect().center(), that's what i need to position my items on the scene, but it doesn't put them in the center.

I am using setTransformationAnchor(QGraphicsView.AnchorUnderMouse) and setResizeAnchor(QGraphicsView.AnchorUnderMouse), but i also tried AnchorViewCenter and it still doesn't position them wright...

Comment: @Cristi Constantin: Have you tried graphicsView.mapToScene(graphicsView.viewport()->rect().center()) to get the center point of the current screen, this should do the job.